# What should be CRUD?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

I read many documentation about CRUD and I still don't understand what exactly should be CRUDable! It seems most of people are talking about CRUD entities but they architecture doesn't show any Create, Read, Update or Delete methods in their entities. They implements these CRUD operations in a separate class. I like to call these kind of classes CRUD controllers.

Is it correct to create POCO entites with CRUD controller? What should be CRUD?

Comment: of course the object itself should not create/update/read/delete others in a persistant sense - it's not it's responsibility. But you would not call the *thing* that does all this *CRUD controller* - you normaly call it **Repository** ^^ ... but I don't get your (only?) question: "What is CreateReadUpdateDelete?" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is that you should have a repository which performs the CRUD operations.

Then a controller should call the appropriate CRUD method in the repository, possibly via an intermediate service layer.

Read more about the repository pattern [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm).

Comment: I like your second link. Thank you. One more question: can I create one repository that manage two POCO entities?

Comment: Yes of course. Usually you would group related entities together and have a repository for those. Or have one repo per aggregate-root. You don't need one repo per entity (although you could if it makes sense for you).

Answer (score 0):

These classes are usually called repositories. A repository provides access to your entities with means of adding, updating, removing and retrieving one or more entities. So the repository Creates, Reads, Updates and Deletes (CRUD).

When using a database your POCO is normally an object your database entity is converted into, e.g. with AutoMapper in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

In architectural terms, CRUD means that you have entities without business rules. This entities, have, at most, some simple validations. When you have this kind of entity you speak of CRUD because you can modify the data without worrying about anything else (but validations). This can be used for example for maintaining a list of contacts: name + phone no. + address: at most you can validate that the name is not empty, the phone no. is valid, and the address is valid. But there are no business rules in there.

If there are involved business rules, you should avoid using CRUD to make sure that the business rules are respected. For example you should not allow CRUD for an order detail, because there are business rules involved: perhaps you cannot change an order detail if the order is already paid or sent, or confirmed to the customer. Besides the total order amount depends on the order details. In this case you should use the order with its details as a whole, and read / write / update it all at once. (In DDD this is called "aggregate").

Speaking about CRUD is not a question of how you implement it (repository, ORM like DbContext or NHibernate, or wichever you want to use), but a more philosophical question.

Implementing CRUD is much faster than implementing any other architecture which involves business rules (for example DDD). If you can use CRUD for an entity, is advisable to use it, but not in the other cases.

As to your comment:

> but they architecture doesn't show any Create, Read, Update or Delete methods in their entities

That's natural... you can do CRUD with EF for example, without explicitly declaring the CRUD methods. Create an entity in the context, or remove it or modify it and the CRUD operations will be implicitly executed on the SaveChanges.